# Commenting out whole file

Tags: c#, java, coding-style, comments

Sometimes, I need to comment out a whole file. Normally, I'd just wrap the class in `/* */`, but that doesn't work if there's already existing comments inside the class:

```
/*
class foo {

    /**
     * Great documentation - but this breaks my 
     * whole-file-comment!
     */
    public void dooFoo() {
    }

}
*/
```

Is there any way to come around this? Preferably without inserting `//`-comments at every line.

Comment: Visual Studio has a "Comment out selected lines" button

Comment: In Visual studio there's the option to set the build action to "None" for the .cs file, and it will not be built (compiled). I don't know if java is capable of that.

Comment: I don't see how this isn't suitable for the Q&A format?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Preferably without inserting //-comments at every line.

That's the simplest way to do it. Most IDEs have keyboard shortcuts to add or remove `//` at the start of every line in a selection - so you just need to select the whole file (e.g. Ctrl-A) and then press the shortcut.

Visual Studio: <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to comment; <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> to uncomment.

Eclipse and IntelliJ: <kbd>Ctrl+/</kbd> to toggle.

IntelliJ: <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+/</kbd> to use `/* ... */`, handling embedded existing comment blocks appropriately.

NetBeans: <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd> to toggle.

Comment: NetBeans: Ctrl + Shift + C to toggle comments.

Comment: @MrLore: Thanks, will add that in :)

Comment: @JonSkeet How do I show those Buttons (In an answer) the way you did? they don't seem like embedded images.

Comment: @AbZy: It's the `<kbd>` tag.

Comment: intellij is ctrl-/ or ctrl-shit-/ for /* */ it is smart enough to escape the existing comment close statements

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [**#if** preprecessor directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) in C#:

```
#if false
... code ...
#endif
```

Comment: Bit late, but good idea. Do you know if there's any equivalent for Java?